# Show sub window in main window

Tags: python-3.x, class, pyqt4

Can't work out how to embed a window in a main window using classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Qt4 tutorial using classes

This example will be built
on over time.
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Form(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super(Form, self).__init__()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1600, 900)
        new_window = Form(self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is supposed to be the single most basic bit of code using classes. How do I get the second window to show please.

Comment: What do you mean by window? A dialog popping up or a widget in the main GUI?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to get the a box up on the main window. It is in the class Form, but I can't get it to just show, I can put a button on the main window and get it to pop up, but I want this embedded.

Comment: The `Form` has no parent, you didn't put it in a layout, and you didn't `show()` it.

Answer (score 1):

As [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) already pointed out, your widget needs to be a child of your mainWindow. However, I do not think that you need to call `show` for the widget, since it anyways gets called as soon as its parent (`MainWindow`) calls `show`. As [mata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata) pointed out correctly, the proper way to add a `Widget` to a `MainWindow` instance is to use `setCentralWidget`. Here is a working example for clarification:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Form(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel("Test", self)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1600, 900)
        new_window = Form(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(new_window)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: No, that's not the right way to use a QMainWindow, to add content to it its [`setCentralWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) method should be used.

Comment: You are right, I was just not sure if [iFunction](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6500048/ifunction) wants ``Form`` to be the ``centralWidget``.

Comment: @alexblae. What I meant, was that you need to do at least *one* of the things I mentioned in order to make the widget visible. Setting it as the central widget is effectively the same as adding it to a layout - in which case, it is not necessary to explicitly set a parent (because it will be automatically re-parented).